# Fix duplicate entries in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically the issue I'm dealing with right now is where propertyID that starts at 4271 through 4342. There is one duplicate Lat and Lng entries (geo-coordinates) that is throwing all the coordinates off .  The latitude and longitude coordinates of propertyID 4272 should be for propertyID 4271. Its off by one propertyID. I essentially need to move the Lat Lng fields up by one.

What would be the best way to go about fixing this using SQL?

photo:
http://bit.ly/KGcRSg

Comment: you have to update those fields.

Comment: well that's one way i thought about doing it. For example: I deleted the duplicate entry then ran an update statement:                   UPDATE Coords
SET
  propertyID = 4271
WHERE
  propertyID = 4272; But isn't there a faster way of doing this instead of updating the ids one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update each record's `propertyID` by an offset like so:

```
UPDATE Coords SET propertyID = propertyID - 1 WHERE propertyID > 4271
```

Comment: i ended up having to delete propertyID 4271 before running this script but this one worked.  thanks!